# How to make it scrollable or prevent from getting out of pixels?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: HELP]

On running the code, The ui is sometime getting out of pixels. How to make it responsive?? Maybe make it scrollabe or something??

Comment: try replacing Column( children []) with ListView( children[])

Answer (score 1):

Generally the easiest way of dealing with Widget overflowing is to wrap this widget or the whole screen in `SingleChildScrollView()`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `Container()` with `SingleChildScrollView()`

```
...
  return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
           height: squareWidth /2,
           width : squareWidth / 2,
          ...

      ),
```